# docker-compose restore database in sql-server-linux

Tags: sql-server, docker, sql-server-linux

I'm following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-docker?view=sql-server-2017 to config and run standalone sqlserver container in macos with persistent data successfully. Now I want to create a docker-compose file which contains 2 things:

1. Web
2. Database (will copy bak file from a host into the container and restore)

How do I achieve (2)?

My docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
    web:
        build: 
            context: ./webapi
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "4010:80"
        environment: 
            - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest"
        ports:
            - "4009:1433"
        volumes:
            - "sqlvolume:/var/opt/mssql"
        environment:
            SA_PASSWORD: "<password>"
            ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    redis:
        image: "redis:alpine"
volumes:
    sqlvolume:
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of different ways to accomplish the restore task. If your backup is on the mounted volume, you could restore using sqlcmd like:

```
run docker exec -it db /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -Usa -P<password> -Q"RESTORE DATABASE YourDatabase FROM DISK='/var/opt/mssql/backup/your-backup.bak';"
```

You could similarly copy the backup into the container using `docker cp` and restore from there.

If your objective is to restore the database from the mounted volume each time the container starts, you can build a custom SQL Server image with the `RESTORE` command (which could be encapsulated in a shell script). Below is a `dockerfile` example:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest

CMD /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -U 'sa' -P $MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD -Q"RESTORE DATABASE YourDatabase FROM DISK='/var/opt/mssql/backup/your-backup.bak';" & /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
```

Comment: But how can I write in dockerfile or docker-compose file? or I just write the above command in there?

Comment: @SteveLam, I added a `dockerfile` example.

Comment: Thank @Dan, it works. Could you let me know how do you know call CMD and also  "& /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr"?

Comment: @SteveLam, the example in the question link shows this method. They key is that the `sqlserver` command needs to be last one to keep the container running, whilst the preceding ones run the background.

Comment: This doesn't work; I get an `Server is not found or not accessible.` error. Before running anything with `sqlcmd` you have to make sure that the SQL server is actually running.